# Does a Jewish idolater's pouring of non-mevushal wine make that wine forbidden to himself?

Tags: halacha, grapes-wine, heterodox, yayin-nesech

We see from [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10492/1713) that wine poured by a Jew who rejects Judaism is *yayin nesech*. Would that cause the wine to be forbidden even to himself, or is it only forbidden to others? Would he be violating halacha every time he drinks non-mevushal wine?

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16577/759

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think its a duplicate (though it's certainly related). But you may wish to copypaste large swaths of [your answer there](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17236) over to here.

Comment: @msh210 My answer there actually relates to a _mumar lechallel shabbos_ not a _mumar la'avoda zarah_.

Comment: JD Bleich had a piece about this in Tradition a few issues back. Need more later.

Comment: I presume you will have the same question about his cooking being subject to bishul akum and whether he may cook for himself on yom tov since one may not cook for a mumar. Is there any reason to believe he should be treated vis-à-vis himself any differently than others treatment of him? I guess a nafka Mina is if he touched the wine and then did teshuva

Comment: @Yoni Another NM is Lifnei Iveir.

Comment: @DoubleAA perhaps... big machlokes according to noda beyhuda no lifneu iver with mumar

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30433/759

Comment: Very similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64320

Comment: Wait, are you asking about an idolater or a heretic?

Comment: @Shalom May a Sabbath-Desecrator Drink Wine? by J. David Bleich http://traditionarchive.org/news/article.cfm?id=105659

Comment: If he's drinking directly from the bottle, then he might avoid the problem... :)

Comment: Are you asking if he poured it for Avodah Zara, or for other purposes?

Comment: @SamuelManuel Not for _Avodah Zara_. For the purpose of drinking it.

Comment: @Daniel then it's stam yainom. Yayin nesech is when it's poured for avoda zorah.

Comment: @user613 Ok. That doesn't change the question.

Comment: What is the side that not. Of course Yes!!!!

Comment: @kouty See the answer. Looks like Rav Feinhandler and Rav Eliyashiv hold "no".

Comment: @Daniel Shkoyech! And Shkoyech for question

Answer (score 1):

The [Avnei Yashfei Chelek 2:61:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=873&st=&pgnum=149) asks a question and offers an answer that may answer this question.

He was asked if one can serve a cup of wine to someone who is a mechalel shabbas.Since once the mechalel shabbas touches the wine he renders it assur and in effect will be drinking yayin nesech.

Rav Feinhandler (the author) answers that it is possible to say that when we prohibit the wine of a mechalel shabbas we are placing a kenas (penalty) to stop his bad behaviors and we "consider" his wine to be like if a non-Jew touched it. He notes that he himself is able to drink the wine since a non-Jew is not prohibited from drinking the wine himself rather we aren't allowed to drink it. Therefore a mechalel shabbas isn't more stringent than a non-Jew and he wouldn't be prohibited from drinking the wine himself. He ends of by saying that it isn't too clear because maybe he gets the status of a non-Jew lechumrah only and would not be allowed to drink it. He also told over this svarah to Rav Eliyashiv who agreed to his psak but not to his reasoning which I just outlined (see the tshuva inside to see why Rav Eliyashiv agreed to allow him to drink it.)

It seems from your question that if he was an actual idol worshiper than its a non-starter and the wine should be prohibited based off an actual issur of receiving benefit from avodah zarah. If you meant a mechalel shabbas then maybe he would be permitted based off this svarah.

Comment: I'm not sure about your penultimate sentence. Even if he was an actual idol worshiper, his wine might not be forbidden to him unless he literally uses _that_ wine for idolatrous purposes.

Comment: The יש לומר at the end of Rav Feinhandler's teshuva is a משמע to me. I don't understand why the fact that a non-Jew is not prohibited from drinking the wine himself means that a _mechalel shabbos_ should also not be prohibited. The _mechalel shabbos_ **is** Jewish, so it wouldn't be surprising to me to say that he has additional restrictions.

Comment: Rav Feinhandler זצ"ל, by the way. :-(