# IVF with eggs or sperm harvested pre conversion

Tags: halacha, infertility

If a couple  harvested eggs or sperm pre conversion of one or both of them, would they be permitted to do IVF with those eggs or sperm post-conversion? And in the case of the eggs, some poskim say the halachic mother is the egg donor (though it’s a minority position)… would the baby be Jewish according to those poskim? Basically can conversion lead to eggs or sperm that were harvested pre conversion having a different Jewish status than the now converts?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first very interesting question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Thank you! I’ve been reading this site for a long time so I thought finally time to join

Comment: Another version: if someone converts, are his severed limbs metameh in an ohel?

Comment: Possibly (but unlikely) related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30433/31534